# Graphs such that every rotation system admits an embedding on a surface of small genus

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, embeddings, topological-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a finite, simple, undirected graph.
**What conditions on $G$ ensure that every rotation system of $G$ corresponds to a cellular embedding of $G$ on an oriented surface of small genus?**
(e.g. genus at most 2)

In particular, **what conditions on a planar graph $G$ ensure that every rotation system of $G$ corresponds to a plane embedding of $G$?**

*Context:* I am interested in rotation systems with a specific property (biparite dual), let us call it property $P$.
I would like to find at least a small class of planar graphs $G$ such that it suffices to check all plane embeddings of $G$ in order to test existence of rotation systems of $G$ with property $P$.

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is "Maximum genus embedding", and this page might also be helpful : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xuong_tree

Comment: @LouisEsperet, Thank you for your comment.

Comment: The notion of maximum genus indeed answers the question. This motivates another question. For a constant g (such as g=2), what conditions on $G$ ensure that every rotation system of $G$ corresponds to an *almost cellular embedding* of $G$ on an oriented surface of genus at most g? (by almost cellular embedding, I mean an embedding in which every face except possibly one is homemorphic to a disk).